# Posts content is display added with title, instead of content, using the_excerpt()

Tags: posts

I have been using WordPress for my blog. Since for few posts the content description shows with title. So the content duplicates.

Ex:

My post has title: xxxxxxxx and description: yyyyyy

But its displaying xxxxxxxxyyyyyy. To display the content I have used `the_excerpt()`.

This is happening for few post only.

Please help me to fix.

Comment: Please show us the code you use.

Comment: This is the part of displaying description`<div class="post_description clearfix">
               <?php // Show Content/Excerpt
                  if(boc_blog_full_post_content()){
                   the_content();
                  }else {
                   the_excerpt();
                  }
                  ?>
            </div>`

Comment: You should edit your question with this information.

Answer (score 0):

That's bizarre. The problem may come from broken html/css with different title or desc lengths. Have you checked the admin to make sure these posts actually don't have description in their title? 
Here is a simple example of showing the title and excerpt in a posts loop.

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2> 
    <div><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
<?php endwhile; <?
```

Comment: `the_excerpt()` returns the data which has title and description together.